# Second button in navbar not working

Tags: ionic2

This is my navbar:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
      <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>JRiver Remote</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name='ion-gear-a'></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

This is exactly how it shows in the documentation, but in the second button for me the icon is invisible. When I inspect it I can see the icon has a height of zero, but the button around it has normal height. The left-side button works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `ion-gear-a` *does not exist*. The name picks up the icon image from [ionicons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/).

If you want a `gear` image try `cog` or `settings`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
      <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>JRiver Remote</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name='settings'></ion-icon><!-- here -->
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Wow... I found that on the Ionicons site though. Thanks